# Reduce the object classes detected with my MobileNet SSD Object Detection using OpenCV 3.4.1 DNN module

Tags: python, opencv, object, tracking

I'm running a python script to detect and track persons with satisfying results. The problem is that I only want to track persons and nothing else but the Caffe model tracks about 20 objects and the created rectangles for cars and other objects overlay the whole picture. Is there any chance to reduce the amount of objects detected? Removing them from the script was not successful, only the label has disappeared.

```
# Import the neccesary libraries
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2 

# construct the argument parse 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Script to run MobileNet-SSD object detection network ')
parser.add_argument("--video", help="path to video file. If empty, camera's stream will be used")
parser.add_argument("--prototxt", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt",
help='Path to text network file: ''MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt for Caffe model or ')
parser.add_argument("--weights", default="MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel",
help='Path to weights: ''MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel for Caffe model or ')
parser.add_argument("--thr", default=0.2, type=float, help="confidence threshold to filter out weak detections")
args = parser.parse_args()

#Load the Caffe model 
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args.prototxt, args.weights)

# Labels of Network.
classNames = { 0: 'background',
    1: 'aeroplane', 2: 'bicycle', 3: 'bird', 4: 'boat',
    5: 'bottle', 6: 'bus', 7: 'car', 8: 'cat', 9: 'chair',
    10: 'cow', 11: 'diningtable', 12: 'dog', 13: 'horse',
    14: 'motorbike', 15: 'person', 16: 'pottedplant',
    17: 'sheep', 18: 'sofa', 19: 'train', 20: 'tvmonitor' }

# Open video file or capture device. 
if args.video:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(args.video)
else:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # cap.open("http://192.168.0.17:8081")

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame,(300, 300)) # resize frame for prediction

    # MobileNet requires fixed dimensions for input image so we have to resize to 300x300 pixels.
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame_resized, 0.007843, (300, 300), (127.5, 127.5, 127.5), False)
    #Set to network the input blob 
    net.setInput(blob)
    #Prediction of network
    detections = net.forward()

    #Size of frame resize (300x300)
    cols = frame_resized.shape[1] 
    rows = frame_resized.shape[0]
    #For get the class and location of object detected, 
    # There is a fix index for class, location and confidence
    # value in @detections array .
    for i in range(detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2] #Confidence of prediction 
        if confidence > args.thr: # Filter prediction 
            class_id = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1]) # Class label

            # Object location 
            xLeftBottom = int(detections[0, 0, i, 3] * cols) 
            yLeftBottom = int(detections[0, 0, i, 4] * rows)
            xRightTop   = int(detections[0, 0, i, 5] * cols)
            yRightTop   = int(detections[0, 0, i, 6] * rows)
            
            # Factor for scale to original size of frame
            heightFactor = frame.shape[0]/300.0  
            widthFactor = frame.shape[1]/300.0 
            # Scale object detection to frame
            xLeftBottom = int(widthFactor * xLeftBottom) 
            yLeftBottom = int(heightFactor * yLeftBottom)
            xRightTop   = int(widthFactor * xRightTop)
            yRightTop   = int(heightFactor * yRightTop)
            # Draw location of object  
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (xLeftBottom, yLeftBottom), (xRightTop, yRightTop),
                          (0, 255, 0),2)

            # Draw label and confidence of prediction in frame resized
            if class_id in classNames:
                label = classNames[class_id] + ": " + str(confidence)
                labelSize, baseLine = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)

                yLeftBottom = max(yLeftBottom, labelSize[1])
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xLeftBottom, yLeftBottom - labelSize[1]),
                                     (xLeftBottom + labelSize[0], yLeftBottom + baseLine),
                                     (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(frame, label, (xLeftBottom, yLeftBottom),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0))

                print(label) #print class and confidence

    cv2.namedWindow("frame", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) >= 0:  # Break with ESC 
        break
```

Comment: pseudo code: if class unwanted, skip all the post processing. Probably in that block before the namedwindow call

Comment: sorry, don't understand what you mean with pseudo code?

Comment: ok... learn a minimum about programming and understand the code you are using. Then just add an if-statement at the right position that asks what kind pf a class a detected object has. If it is of an unwanted class, skip any further processing for that object.

Comment: thanks for your advice. The implementation was not difficult and the result is satisfying. Actually i was hoping to prevent the detection stage to reduce the CPU load but this is probably impossible.

Comment: probably ssd is similar to yolo. In theiry you can just prune all the connections in the last layer which belong to the unwabted classes, but wont guve a good speedup, because the main "work" is done in the general feature extractor layers. You could try to create a reduced network with less classes, but then a full training is absolutely necessary.

Comment: and it might even be hard to reach original teaining quality

Comment: that's what i think too. It exceeds my current programming knowledge.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75527638/18667225